# Highway.module.js library cannot load (throws an error)

Tags: javascript, gulp

Trying to implement highway page transition using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTbCzhDpBHc).

But whenever I turn on the localhost server I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')
    at ./node_modules/@dogstudio/highway/build/highway.module.js.n.getSlug (highway.module.js:1:2384)
    at ./node_modules/@dogstudio/highway/build/highway.module.js.n.getProperties (highway.module.js:1:3032)
    at new e (highway.module.js:1:3465)
    at ./src/js/main.js (main.js:4:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at bootstrap:83:1
    at bootstrap:83:1
```

**main.js:**

```js
import Highway from "@dogstudio/highway";
import Fade from "./transition.js";

const H = new Highway.Core({
    transitions: {
        default: Fade
    }
});
```

**transition.js:**

```js
import Highway from '@dogstudio/highway';
import Tween from 'gsap';

class Fade extends Highway.Transition {
    in({from,to,done}) {
        // removing old content
        from.remove();

        // actual animation
        Tween.fromTo(to, 0.5, {opacity:0}, {opacity:1, onComplete: done})
    }
    out({from, done}) {
        done();
    }
}

export default Fade;
```

I believe I'm missing some libraries in my project or there is a version conflict within dogstudio highway library. Using gulp and sass for the project.

Tried using different dogstudio highway versions, searching for an error in google and github. Version changes didn't help. Didn't find anything when searching as well.

Thanks in advance!